# React Native KeyboardAvoidigView does not work with SafeAreaView

Tags: react-native

`KeyboardAvoidingView` does not seem to be working properly with `SafeAreaView` and not sure where is the issue come from.

Can anyone help me find the issue?

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
    <Text
      style={styles.goBackText}
      onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.goBack()}}><Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" size={28} /></Text>
    {/* TODO: KeyboardAvoidingView does not work properly */}
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
      <View style={styles.formView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Email"
          onChangeText={(email) => this.props.screenProps[1](email) }
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.props.screenProps[2](password) }
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnStyle} onPress={this.userLoginClicked}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeArea: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: '#eee'
  },
  viewStyle: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#eee'
  },
  goBackText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    left: 16
  },
  formView: {
    padding: 16,
  },
  textInput: {
    padding: 14,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  btnStyle: {
    padding: 14,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fc0f82',
  },
  btnText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#f8f8f8'
  },
  errorText: {
    color: '#ff0000',
    marginBottom: 10
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, remove the flex:1 in the styles for the safeArea component

Change the this style from

```
  safeArea: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: '#eee'
  }
```

to

```
  safeArea: {
    flex:0,
    backgroundColor: '#eee'
  }
```